# Line-height with alignment inside;

Tags: css, html

It seems my issue was never asked - or probably I'm not smart enough to find it:

Is there a way to align vertically a element inside its line-height through CSS?

**Example and Code**

Link to the example image:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/92lia6rdl9nyanq/Example.png

***HTML***

```
<article class="news-content news-content-1">
    <h1 class="news-title">
         Hello World!
    </h1>
</article>
```

***CSS***

```
.news-content.news-content-1 news-title 
{ 
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

I'll specify a little more: I want it to act as a vertically aligned element (center) inside the the **ARTICLE**, and I need the **LINE-HEIGHT** set to **1.5** but this extra height is set below the element and I need it to be centered in it.

I will appreciate any help.

**EDIT:**

The image shows 'line-height: 1.5px;' but it is actually only 'line-height: 1.5', sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seeing with the inspector isn't the line-height, but rather the padding. [Check this fiddle out](http://jsfiddle.net/g5QjD/).

I've set the `margin` and the `padding` of the `h1` to `0`, and the `line-height` to `1.5`. Try changing the line height and seeing the difference.

Text is always vertically centered within its line height.

Comment: I see know, thanks. I'll mark as correct as soon as it is possible. Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry for not up-voting you, I got no reputation.

Comment: No problem, glad to have helped!